# Code is being ran before for loop has finished, thread pool c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am trying to execute code inside a thread first and wait until the for loop is finished before executing the code after the for loop.

```
for (int i = 254; i > 1; i--)
{

    //some code here...

    WaitCallback func = delegate (object state)
    {
        //do something here.... - i want this to finish with the loop first
    };

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(func);

}

// this code is executed once the for loop has finished
// however i want it to be done 
// after the thread has finished executing its code and the for loop.
```

Comment: so do you want to span 254 threads ?

Comment: yes, I would like to do this....

Comment: @Tigran It's using the thread pool, so it won't actually use 254 threads.  It's simply scheduling 254 operations to be performed by the thread pool in whatever way the thread pool considers most optimal, which won't involve 254 actual threads.

Comment: @Servy yes that's correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use TPL to queue your work and call `Task.WaitAll` right after the loop:

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[254];
for (int i = 254; i > 1; i--)
{

    //some code here...

    Task task = TaskFactory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        //do something here.... - i want this to finish with the loop first
    });
    tasks[i - 1] = task;
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks);

// do other stuff
```

TPL will ultimately use ThreadPool to perform the work.

PS. I didn't run it or anything, so there might an off-by-one error with array access, but you should get the general idea behind the approach.

**Edit**

As eocron mentioned in a comment, using [`Parallel.For`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for(v=vs.110).aspx) might also be an option.

Comment: I will give this ago . Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Isn't it better to use Parallel.For(...) for this?

Comment: @eocron That would depend on the type of code that's inside the delegate, wouldn't it? But yeah, that's definitely another approach to look at. Added that to the answer.

Comment: One isn't necessarily better than the other.  It's like asking if a wrench is better than a screwdriver.  Both turn things, but you'd use the tool that is most applicable and most effective.to your task.

Comment: Don't use TaskFactory.StartNew. There are very few situations where the default parameters are the right option. Use Task.Run to get behaviour that will be the right choice in most situations (if you don't know when specific parameters would make sense you secondly want to stick with Task.Run). But yes in this case the parallel class is the better choice anyhow.

Comment: @Amy What's the difference between the two approaches? And under what circumstances would one be preferable to the other? That seems like a handwavy claim, considering that both use the same underlying infrastructure, with Parallel.* just avoiding the need for writing code and providing additional features at no cost.

Comment: @Voo I suggest you ask on Stack Overflow.  And features always have a cost.

Comment: @Amy The point is that both use the same underlying infrastructure, so there is no difference and it's very, very clear which one is the better approach for this particular problem: The one that doesn't allow you to make easy mistakes (like using `Task.Factory.StartNew` without specifying the right sync context) and gives you additional features (like allowing you to pass a CancellationToken around) at no cost (the whole infrastructure already exists, you're just choosing not to use it in the manual code).

Comment: Hi, I have tried to implement the code that  @MarcinJuraszek  provided.  I get the following error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TaskFactory.StartNew(Action)'